# How to make function that calculates the probability of two bugs will meet within $8$s timesteps?

Tags: probability, logic

I have the following problem:

You have $2$ bugs on a line. They are initially $10$ centimeters apart. Every one second, each bug will independently move left by $1$ centimeter with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ or right by $1$ centimeter with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

$1.$ After $8$ seconds, what is the probability that the bugs met at some point in time?

I did the following code but I want confirmation if the answers are correct: the following code return probability in an exact timestep. so for example at $5$s we only have one scenario they will meet out of ($2^{10}$) possibilities. and at $6$s we have $14$ scenarios they will meet out of ($2^{12}$) and so on..I just want to know the answer of $8$s timesteps.

My answer is $\frac{834}{2^{16}}$

```
function antMove(dirB, distance, depth, time, met) {
    distance = distance - dirB;
    
    let count = 0;
    if (distance === 0) {
      met = true;
    } 
    if (depth === time) {
        if(met === true){
            count = 1;
        }
        else count =0
      return count;
    }
    else{
      depth++;
      count += antMove(-2, distance, depth, time, met);
      count += antMove(2, distance, depth, time, met);
      count += antMove(0, distance, depth, time, met);
      count += antMove(0, distance, depth, time, met);
    }
      return count;
  }

function probability(dirB, distance, depth, time, met){
    return antMove(dirB, distance, depth, time, met)/Math.pow(2,time*2)
}

const result = probability(0, 10, 0, 5,false);
console.log(result);
```

Please if there is anything which is not clear let me know to clarify more.

Thank you for your time and help :)